# default selected value in xforms:select1

Tags: xml, xhtml, xforms

How can I set the selected value to a select1 in xforms without using the instance?

For example, i have this instance:

```
<lEmpleado_Id></lEmpleado_Id>
<sEmpleado_Nm xsi:type="xs:string"></sEmpleado_Nm>
<iCargo_Id xsi:type="xs:int"></iCargo_Id>
<iProfesion_Id xsi:type="xs:int"></iProfesion_Id>

<iHorario_Id xsi:type="xs:int"></iHorario_Id>
<iConcurrencia_Id>1</iConcurrencia_Id>
```

and I want to make this select1 to take a default value:

```
<xf:select1 ref="iHorario_Id">
    <xf:label>Horario</xf:label>
    <!--This is the default item I Want to be selected-->
    <xf:item>
        <xf:label>Select a schedule...</xf:label>
        <xf:value>0</xf:value>
    </xf:item>
    <!--End Here-->
    <xf:item>
        <xf:label>Schedule 1</xf:label>
        <xf:value>1</xf:value>
    </xf:item>
</xf:select1>
```

but when I validate the xforms I want that if that item is selected, the xform don't submit, but if any other item is selected, it submit normally, Ive tryed with `<xf:bind` but I don't know how to put a minvalue or something like that to that element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xforms:bind` is the right direction; you just need to put a [constraint](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-xforms-20091020/#model-prop-constraint) on the `iHorario_Id` element:

```
<xf:bind nodeset="iHorario_Id" constraint=". gt 0" />
```

This makes `iHorario_Id` valid only if its value is greater than 0. So, you could set the initial value of `iHorario_Id` to 0 to prevent any submission until a schedule is selected.

Comment: thanks! it works like a charm, but I had to use ">" symbol instead of "gt" because it gave me a parser error

Comment: `gt` is an XPath 2 operator, so if your implementation uses XPath 1 you have to use `>` instead.